Finding the equation of a hexagon given the area

When I tried solving a linear programming problem, I was stuck. Based on the image given, I would like to find the equation that connects say, DE, given that the area of the hexagon is 360 units squared. But I can't seem to think of a way to do it. Any sort of hints would help a lot. Thanks in advanced.
Edit:
Turns out the equation indeed was complicated:
$y=\frac{\sqrt[4]{675-75^3}}{75}x-6\sqrt[4]{675}$

The hexagon consists of 6 equilateral triangles with, say, side length  $a$. The area then is given by $\frac{\sqrt3}4 a^2$. Thus $360=6\frac{\sqrt3}{4} a^2$. These leads to an expression for $a$ which seems to be a Goodyear starting point.

First you calculate the edge length s by the formula $s^2=2A/(3*\sqrt{3})$ the distance of C you find by  OC=s*sin(30°) The rest is for you to do.

I feel like this is overcomplicating the calculations. Can you think of anything else?

As mentioned in the comments by @JensSchwaiger, hexagon consists of $6$ equilateral triangles. Thus, $360=6 \frac{\sqrt{3}}{4} a^2 \implies a=4\sqrt{15}$. Hence, point $D$ has coordinates $(6\sqrt{15},0)$. You also know the slope of the line $DE$ is $\tan 60^\circ=\sqrt{3}$. Putting it all together, the equation of the line $DE$ is $y=\sqrt{3}x-18\sqrt{5}$
